# Is "choosability of subsets" NP-hard?

Tags: np-hardness, np-complete

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a positive integer, and let ${\cal A}$ be a collection of subsets of $n=\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$. We say ${\cal A}$ has the *choosability property* if there is $R\subseteq n$ such that $|R\cap B|=1$ for all $B\in {\cal A}$.

Given $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and ${\cal A}\subseteq {\cal P}(n)$, is the problem of deciding whether ${\cal A}$ has the choosability property, NP-hard?

Comment: Isn't there an easy reduction from 3D-matching?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and one can give a reduction from one-in-three 3SAT, which is the following problem: given a conjunctive normal form with three literals per clause, the problem is to determine whether there exists a truth assignment to the variables so that each clause has exactly one true literal.

Let $\varphi = C_1 \land \dots \land C_m$ be a 3CNF formula in which the variables $\{x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$ occur. Consider the following family $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $\{0,\dots,2n - 1\}$. First, for every $0\leq i \leq n-1$ we add the set $\{2i,2i+1\}$ to $\mathcal{A}$. Then, for every clause $C_k = (\ell_1 \lor \ell_2 \lor \ell_3)$ we add the set $\{i_1,i_2,i_3\}$, where $i_j$ is $2i$, if $\ell_j = x_i$, and $2i+1$, if $\ell_j = \neg x_i$. We now claim that $\mathcal{A}$ has the choosability property iff $\varphi$ has a truth assignment to the variables $\{x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$ so that each clause has exactly one true literal.

Suppose first that there exists $R \subseteq \{0,\dots,2n - 1\}$ such that for every $B \in \mathcal{A}$ we have that $|R \cap B| = 1$. Since we added $\{2i,2i+1\}$ to $\mathcal{A}$, for every $0 \leq i \leq n - 1$, $R$ encodes the following truth assignment to the variables $\{x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$: $s(x_i) = 1$ if $2i \in R$ and $s(x_i) = 0$ if $2i+1 \in R$. Note that $R$ can be viewed as the set of literals that $s$ makes true. Now we claim that $s$ makes exactly one literal in each clause of $\varphi$ true: but this just follows from the fact that $|R \cap \{i_1,i_2,i_3\}| = 1$, for every $\{i_1,i_2,i_3\} \in \mathcal{A}$.

Conversely, if there exists a truth assignment $s$ to the variables $\{x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$ so that each clause has exactly one true literal, then we can define
$$R = \{2i \mid 0 \leq i \leq n - 1 \text{ and } s(x_i) = 1\} \ \cup \ \{2i+1 \mid 0 \leq i \leq n - 1 \text{ and } s(x_i) = 0\}. $$
Clearly $R$ has the desired properties.